# Access Denied on AWS S3 bucket with no permission set up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

In our S3 configuration we have a bucket that ended up without any permissions, which I reckon my colleague deleted.

Now, we cannot read this bucket, I cannot add permissions to it using the management console, selecting grantee and the permission, as it says "Sorry! You do not have permissions to view this bucket.", When I click on "Add Bucket policy", it opens the dialog which says "Loading" and it keeps loading forever.

I've tried to use aws s3 and aws s3api to grand permission and/or delete the bucket with no success.

I want to either delete this bucket or change it's permissions.

EDIT: We also noticed that the bucket has no owner.

Comment: Sounds like you need to get your root user to try this or reach out to AWS Support.

Comment: Thank you. I've read something about this somewhere else, I'm just awaiting to see the account owner tomorrow and confirm he can do that. From my IAM profile, I had the impression I could do all of that, as I can change permissions of S3 buckets that do no belong to me in my account. Perhaps this is a bug (or a feature?)

Answer (score 0):

In the Amazon S3 Management Console:

- Select the bucket (don't click on its name, just click the line it is on)
- Go to the **Properties** pane on the right
- Expand the **Permissions** section
- If there is no line displayed, click **Add more permissions**, then select the Grantee (possibly your account name?) and tick some permission boxes

These permissions are on the Bucket itself.

Permissions to list the contents of an Amazon S3 bucket are normally granted via Identity and Access Management (**IAM**) rather than a bucket policy. Traditionally, bucket policies are used to grant access to objects within a bucket.

From your description, it appears that there is **no bucket policy** in place, which is perfectly okay. All new buckets have no bucket policy anyway.

If the above fix doesn't work, you should check your permissions in IAM to see what you are permitted to do in Amazon S3:

- Is there a policy granting you access to everything in S3 (`s3:*`), or at least a policy granting you access to this bucket?
- Is there a policy that is explicitly **denying** access to this bucket? (Deny overrides Allow)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and apologies if I wasn't clear. That's what I meant by trying to change it in the management console. From my IAM profile, I've got full permissions on the account.